# SQL - MATCH AGAINST doesn't work

Tags: php, sql

I'm developing an Android application where I want to search a MySQL database based on multiple criteria. For that I'm using a MATCH/AGAINST statement. For some reason that statement only works sometimes. It works fine when I do like this:

```
$search_query="'Candreva' IN BOOLEAN MODE"; 
      $sql = 'SELECT * from spillere where MATCH(fornavn,efternavn,placering) AGAINST(:search_query)';
```

Here it finds everyone in the database with the name "Candreva". But when I do like this it doesn't work:

```
$search_query="'Candre*' IN BOOLEAN MODE";  
      $sql = 'SELECT * from spillere where MATCH(fornavn,efternavn,placering) AGAINST(:search_query)';
```

Here it should be finding everyone where the name starts with "Candre" but it doesn't.

This is how i created my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `spillere` (
`fornavn` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`efternavn` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`placering` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`rating` int(2) NOT NULL,
FULLTEXT KEY `my_index` (`fornavn`,`efternavn`,`placering`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And this is what my table looks like:

[image]

Why am I only able to perform some of the statements and not all of them?

Comment: It works just fine. [See this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc70ae/1). Your problem is elsewhere, not with that query on that table.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Yes the query is correct, but when I run it in phpMyAdmin it doesn't work. Is it something with the settings in phpMyAdmin you think?

Comment: In phpMyAdmin, I don't think you can enter a query with parameters (don't use `:search_query`), you'll need to manually insert `'Candre*' IN BOOLEAN MODE` into the query.

Comment: @BeetleJuice I have tried that as well. It still only works sometimes, and I think it's very random what works and what doesn't.